# Difference between charge-sharing and charge-redistrbution

Tags: charge

I've come across these two phenonmenon in several places but I want to know - what's the difference between them in a general two capacitor circuit case (not related to SAR ADCs)

Like if I have two unequally charged capacitors in parallel with a switch in the middle. When I close the switch - does charge sharing occur or charge redistribution?

Comment: I think you're getting a bit hung up on the semantics of the words used, especially since neither word has a technical definition. If I give you half of my piece of pie, and I am sharing the pie? Or am I redistributing it? Does it really matter which it is? Is there even a difference?

Comment: Redistribution certainly occurs. Voltage equalisation certainly occurs. You might want to think about the definition of the word 'sharing' if the capacitors are different sizes, like if you and @DKNguyen are different sizes, do you get different amounts of pie?

Comment: @DKNguyen That's exactly what I thought at first but I wondered, if both words are used, perhaps it had some feature that distinugished them. I guess not. Thanks